# Geogode street intersection with free-form input Geocoder API

Tags: here-api

I am trying to geocode a street interception through Here Geocoder API Forward Geocoding. However, with no success.

There is some example in the documentation:
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-intersection
There is an obvious way to do what I want.However, there is a proxy endpoint, which I am not allowed to change and it accepts from client and passes to Here API only free form input.

I tried with the following string for my free form input value,it is the same as the documentation example:
State @ Madison, Chicago
But got 0 results.

I just wonder if that is possible at all through  Here Forward Geocoding-it seems difficult for implementation without some restriction to the free-form input format?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the result for street intersection with it, can you please try by using your appkey, id.

> https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?city=Chicago&street=State%20and%20Madison&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&gen=9

if the search needs to be in free form, then below API call can work too, but here the search match level is based out of the city, not specific to street.

> https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=200%20S%20Mathilda%20Sunnyvale%20CA&app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&gen=9